# android recording video and playing it back immediately

Tags: android, orientation, android-videoview, mediarecorder

hi guys i have been trying to record a video with front camera and the playing it back using the videoview and mediacontroller. But facing the orientation problem, as i record the video with camera orientation set to 90 degree(PORTRAIT) but when the recorded video is played it doesnot play in PORTRAIT mode instead it plays in landscape mode. Also have tried setting the media recorder object's setOrientationHint method to 180 degree. Still with no success. Hope someone could have faced or solved this issue and hoping for better responses. Thanks in advance. If needed i can post my code snippets too.

Comment: I'm not quite sure... but I remember there's a "setRotation" in camera parameters: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html

Comment: @songyy i have also tried setting the camera rotation to 90, still no change.

Answer (score 0):

rotate videoview to 90 degree.

Comment: can you please elaborate in detail... :-)

Comment: I think you can rotate your videoview  through mentioning rotation in xml.